# Why does VSCode not recognize the JavaScript spread operator and autocompletes instead?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, spread-syntax

I have been struggling with a really annoying behaviour of Visual Studio Code recently.

Whenever I try to use the JavaScript [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) VSCode automatically autocompletes the next piece of code (wrongly). Note I am NOT hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Here's a demonstration of what I'm talking about:

[image: Annoying autocomplete behaviour demonstration]

Is there a way to disable this? This is really driving me mad...
I am using **Visual Studio Code 1.59.0** (which should be the latest release at the time of authoring this question).

Comment: in my setup it only gives the intellisence suggestions when I have typed `...`. What if you try with all extensions disabled.

Comment: OMFG YES THANK YOU! I'm not going insane.. this is new and a MIGHTY PITA!!
I will try and implement one of the suggestions and hope this goes away.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment elsewhere, the github issue is [Typing repeated dots in js expands to first suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130096).

In that issue a couple of temporary fixes are mentioned:

`"editor.suggest.showWords": false`

or

`"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false`

The `.`'s are commit characters in javascript and so one of the suggestions will be selected that you do not want.

[You might be able to increase the `quick suggestions delay` time as a possible fix, but I can't test that since I can't actually repro this bug on my setup.]

[If you still are facing this problem make sure to upgrade to v1.59.1, which included a fix.  If that doesn't fix it for you, file an issue.]

Answer (score 3):

**It appears to be an issue introduced in the latest update to VSCode.**

I have one laptop running the latest version that is exhibiting the issue. And another laptop that was running an older version and did not exhibit the issue. Upon updating the laptop with the older version to the latest it too now has this annoying bug...

EDIT: 
As a temporary fix I just reinstalled version 1.58.2 on my laptops which has resolved the issue.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_58

Comment: Here is the issue with a couple of temporary fixes:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130096.  @Reid187 You could add this info and fixes to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I made a user snippet to work around the issue for now:

```json
  "Spread": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "spd",
    "body": ["...$1"],
    "description": "spread rest operator vs code fix"
  }
```

Basic but does the job. Just create a snippet and drop it in.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed in the latest commit, which is 1.59.1.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many causes for this problem,
try to: install js extentions
If doesn't work try to delete the .vscode folder under your home dir and reinstall vscode, this should solve the problem.

Comment: I was actually hoping somebody would be able to reproduce the *issue* and has found a concrete solution. Nevertheless thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

## Here is how to fix that

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (control + comma)
- Type `editor.suggest.showWords` in the search box
- `Uncheck` the Setting,  (It says `When enabled intellisense shows text-suggestions`)

**Or to disable it specifically for javascript**

Add the line `"editor.suggest.showWords": false` in `settings.json`, inside the `[javascript]` section.

You can open settings.json by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, and typing `settings.json`

More information about this issue and the temporary fix can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130096) on the github issue on the official vscode repository